# How to use require(googlesheets) properly?

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I recently downloaded `googlesheets` via

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/googlesheets")
```

and experience some difficulties. When running the script as mentioned in 
https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets I get always:

```
Error: could not find function "%>%"
```

How can I solve that problem?

Reproducible example:

Download:

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/googlesheets")
require(googlesheets)
```

Data:

```
gap_key <- "1HT5B8SgkKqHdqHJmn5xiuaC04Ngb7dG9Tv94004vezA"
copy_ss(key = gap_key, to = "Gapminder")
gap <- register_ss("Gapminder")
```

Error occurs:

```
oceania_csv <- gap %>% get_via_csv(ws = "Oceania")
```

Answer (score 6):

Load the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package first, which provides the `%>%` operator. This is noted [here](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets#load-googlesheets) in the README you link to (`suppressMessages` is optional):

> googlesheets is designed for use with the %>% pipe operator and, to a lesser extent, the data-wrangling mentality of dplyr. The examples here use both, but we'll soon develop a vignette that shows usage with plain vanilla R. googlesheets uses dplyr internally but does not require the user to do so.

```
library("googlesheets")
suppressMessages(library("dplyr"))
```

You can install dplyr with

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

See [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/) for more about the pipe operator (`%>%`).

Comment: Strictly speaking the  `magrittr` package provides the `%>%` operator, but `dplyr` imports and re-exports it, making it available to users. You can just `require(magrittr)` and the pipe operator should work.